# JPanel only showing components sometimes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm having a problem with JPanel. I'm new to Swing and everything, so some of it may be incorrect. Any help would be appreciated. The problem is occurring in the second class when the battleGUISelection method is called. Sometimes it will show, but other times, like after adding a new move via teachMove method, it will show up blank. The JLabels will be entirely invisible and the buttons will not appear until i hover over them with the cursor.

Here is what i have so far...

```
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class Battle {

public int hp;
public String name;
public ArrayList<String> moves = new ArrayList<String>();   
public ArrayList<Integer> damages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public Battle(String name_in)
{
    name = name_in;

    moves.add("punch");
    moves.add("kick");
    moves.add("slam");

    damages.add(10);
    damages.add(15);
    damages.add(20);
}



public void setHp(Battle player, int amt)
{
    player.hp = amt;
}

public void revive(Battle player, String difficulty_in)
{
    if(difficulty_in.equals("beginner"))
    {
        player.hp = 50;
    }
    else if(difficulty_in.equals("intermediate"))
    {
        player.hp = 75;
    }
    else if(difficulty_in.equals("expert"))
    {
        player.hp = 100;
    }
}
}
```

and the gui class..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIFrameTest extends JFrame {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton begButton = new JButton("Beginner");
        JButton intermButton = new JButton("Intermediate");
        JButton expertButton = new JButton("Expert");
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        JLabel title = new JLabel("SELECT DIFFICULTY");
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JLabel txtLabel = new JLabel();
        TextField name = new TextField();    

    static Battle newPlayer = new Battle("");
    static Battle enemyBeginner = new Battle("OPPONENT");
    static Battle enemyIntermediate = new Battle("OPPONENT");
static Battle enemyExpert = new Battle("OPPONENT");
static Battle enemy;
static String difficulty;

public GUIFrameTest(String windowName) 
{
    super(windowName);

    final Container c = getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    //panel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

    begButton.setBounds(0, 25, 100, 50);
    intermButton.setBounds(125, 25, 110, 50);
    expertButton.setBounds(255, 25, 100, 50);
    label.setBounds(0, 100, 200, 50);
    name.setBounds(188, 225, 125, 25);
    txtLabel.setBounds(188, 178, 125, 50);
    okButton.setBounds(200, 255, 100, 25);
    title.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 15);

    txtLabel.setText("Enter name of player: ");


    begButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            label.setText("Difficulty set to beginner");
            difficulty = "beginner";
            newPlayer.setHp(newPlayer, 50);
            enemyBeginner.setHp(enemyBeginner, 50);
            enemyBeginner.moves.add("punch");
            enemyBeginner.moves.add("kick");
            enemyBeginner.damages.add(10);
            enemyBeginner.damages.add(10);
            enemy = enemyBeginner;
        }
    });
    intermButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            label.setText("Difficulty set to intermediate");
            difficulty = "intermediate";
            newPlayer.setHp(newPlayer, 75);
            enemyIntermediate.setHp(enemyIntermediate, 75);
            enemyIntermediate.moves.add("punch");
            enemyIntermediate.moves.add("kick");
            enemyIntermediate.moves.add("slam");
            enemyIntermediate.damages.add(20);
            enemyIntermediate.damages.add(15);
            enemyIntermediate.damages.add(25); 
            enemy = enemyIntermediate;
        }
    });
    expertButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            label.setText("Difficulty set to expert");
            difficulty = "expert";
            newPlayer.setHp(newPlayer, 100);
            enemyExpert.setHp(enemyExpert, 100);
            enemyExpert.moves.add("super punch");
            enemyExpert.moves.add("smash");
            enemyExpert.moves.add("jump kick");
            enemyExpert.damages.add(20);
            enemyExpert.damages.add(25);
            enemyExpert.damages.add(30); 
            enemy = enemyExpert;

        }
    });
    okButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            newPlayer.name = name.getText();
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.updateUI();
            battleGUISelection(c);
        }
    });

    panel.add(begButton);
    panel.add(intermButton);
    panel.add(expertButton);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(name);
    panel.add(txtLabel);
    panel.add(okButton);
    panel.add(title);

    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    c.add(panel);           
}

public static void battleGUISelection(final Container c)
{       
    int yCoord = 100;

    final JPanel nextPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel title = new JLabel();

    nextPanel.updateUI();

    ArrayList<JLabel> moveLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    ArrayList<JLabel> damageLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    title.setText("Moves Known: ");
    title.setBounds(200, 75, 100, 30);

    nextPanel.setLayout(null);  

    JButton battleButton = new JButton("Battle");
    JButton moveButton = new JButton("Teach Moves");
    JButton healButton = new JButton("Heal");

    battleButton.setBounds(0, 360, 500, 30);
    moveButton.setBounds(0, 390, 500, 30);
    healButton.setBounds(0, 420, 500, 30);

    moveButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            nextPanel.removeAll();
            nextPanel.updateUI();
            teachMove(c, nextPanel);

        }
    });

    nextPanel.add(battleButton);
    nextPanel.add(moveButton);
    nextPanel.add(healButton);
    nextPanel.add(title);

    for(int i=0; i<newPlayer.moves.size(); i++)
    {
        moveLabelList.add(new JLabel(newPlayer.moves.get(i).toString()));
        moveLabelList.get(i).setBounds(185, yCoord, 100, 15);
        yCoord=yCoord+25;
        nextPanel.add(moveLabelList.get(i));
    }

    yCoord = 100;

    for(int x=0; x<newPlayer.damages.size(); x++)
    {
        damageLabelList.add(new JLabel(newPlayer.damages.get(x).toString() + " damage"));
        damageLabelList.get(x).setBounds(280, yCoord, 100, 15);
        yCoord=yCoord+25;
        nextPanel.add(damageLabelList.get(x));
    }


    nextPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //nextPanel.setVisible(true);
    c.setVisible(true); 
    c.add(nextPanel);
}

public static void teachMove(final Container x, final JPanel newPanel)
{
    final int confirmYOrN = 0;

    final JTextField moveName = new JTextField();
    final JSlider moveDamage = new JSlider(0, 30);
    final JLabel confirm = new JLabel("Great! Your move has been added.");

    JLabel entryLabel = new JLabel("Enter the new move's name: ");
    JLabel damageEntryLabel = new JLabel("Enter the new move's damage: ");
    JButton enterButton = new JButton("OK");

    confirm.setBounds(160, 350, 200, 15);

    enterButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add"){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            final String mName = moveName.getText();
            final int mDam = moveDamage.getValue();
            newPlayer.moves.add(mName);
            newPlayer.damages.add(mDam);

            newPanel.removeAll();
            newPanel.updateUI();

            battleGUISelection(x);

        }
    });

    moveDamage.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    moveDamage.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    moveDamage.setPaintTicks(true);
    moveDamage.setPaintLabels(true);

    entryLabel.setBounds(160, 125, 175, 25);
    damageEntryLabel.setBounds(160, 200, 200, 25);
    moveName.setBounds(160, 155, 175, 25);
    moveDamage.setBounds(160, 230, 175, 45);
    enterButton.setBounds(225, 290, 60, 50);

    newPanel.add(entryLabel);
    newPanel.add(moveName);
    newPanel.add(damageEntryLabel);
    newPanel.add(moveDamage);
    newPanel.add(enterButton);

    x.add(newPanel);
    x.setVisible(true); 
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GUIFrameTest window = new GUIFrameTest("BattleGUI");
     //Window properties
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 500, 500);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}    
}
```

Comment: Avoid null layout and look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Also, when removing components from a container, make sure to call `validate()` and `repaint()`.

Comment: Sidenote: Why are you using null layout?

Comment: Sometimes? See also [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've taken you're basic GUI code and changed to use a series of layouts...

```
public class GUICompoundLayout extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton begButton = new JButton("Beginner");
    JButton intermButton = new JButton("Intermediate");
    JButton expertButton = new JButton("Expert");
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    JLabel title = new JLabel("SELECT DIFFICULTY");
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JLabel txtLabel = new JLabel();
    TextField name = new TextField(10);
    static Battle newPlayer = new Battle("");
    static Battle enemyBeginner = new Battle("OPPONENT");
    static Battle enemyIntermediate = new Battle("OPPONENT");
    static Battle enemyExpert = new Battle("OPPONENT");
    static Battle enemy;
    static String difficulty;

    public GUICompoundLayout(String windowName) {
        super(windowName);

        JPanel pnlTop = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel pnlMiddle = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel pnlBody = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        pnlTop.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pnlMiddle.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pnlBody.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        pnlTop.add(title);
        pnlMiddle.add(begButton);
        pnlMiddle.add(intermButton);
        pnlMiddle.add(expertButton);

        txtLabel.setText("Enter name of player: ");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        pnlBody.add(txtLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        pnlBody.add(name, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        pnlBody.add(okButton, gbc);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        add(pnlTop, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(pnlMiddle, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(pnlBody, gbc);

//        begButton.setBounds(0, 25, 100, 50);
//        intermButton.setBounds(125, 25, 110, 50);
//        expertButton.setBounds(255, 25, 100, 50);
//        label.setBounds(0, 100, 200, 50);
//        name.setBounds(188, 225, 125, 25);
//        txtLabel.setBounds(188, 178, 125, 50);
//        okButton.setBounds(200, 255, 100, 25);
//        title.setBounds(0, 0, 150, 15);
//
//        txtLabel.setText("Enter name of player: ");


        begButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Difficulty set to beginner");
                difficulty = "beginner";
                newPlayer.setHp(newPlayer, 50);
                enemyBeginner.setHp(enemyBeginner, 50);
                enemyBeginner.moves.add("punch");
                enemyBeginner.moves.add("kick");
                enemyBeginner.damages.add(10);
                enemyBeginner.damages.add(10);
                enemy = enemyBeginner;
            }
        });
        intermButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Difficulty set to intermediate");
                difficulty = "intermediate";
                newPlayer.setHp(newPlayer, 75);
                enemyIntermediate.setHp(enemyIntermediate, 75);
                enemyIntermediate.moves.add("punch");
                enemyIntermediate.moves.add("kick");
                enemyIntermediate.moves.add("slam");
                enemyIntermediate.damages.add(20);
                enemyIntermediate.damages.add(15);
                enemyIntermediate.damages.add(25);
                enemy = enemyIntermediate;
            }
        });
        expertButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText("Difficulty set to expert");
                difficulty = "expert";
                newPlayer.setHp(newPlayer, 100);
                enemyExpert.setHp(enemyExpert, 100);
                enemyExpert.moves.add("super punch");
                enemyExpert.moves.add("smash");
                enemyExpert.moves.add("jump kick");
                enemyExpert.damages.add(20);
                enemyExpert.damages.add(25);
                enemyExpert.damages.add(30);
                enemy = enemyExpert;

            }
        });
        okButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newPlayer.name = name.getText();
                panel.removeAll();
                panel.updateUI();
                battleGUISelection(getContentPane());
            }
        });

//        panel.add(begButton);
//        panel.add(intermButton);
//        panel.add(expertButton);
//        panel.add(label);
//        panel.add(name);
//        panel.add(txtLabel);
//        panel.add(okButton);
//        panel.add(title);

//        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

//        c.add(panel);
    }

    public static void battleGUISelection(final Container c) {
        int yCoord = 100;

        final JPanel nextPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel title = new JLabel();

        nextPanel.updateUI();

        ArrayList<JLabel> moveLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        ArrayList<JLabel> damageLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

        title.setText("Moves Known: ");
        title.setBounds(200, 75, 100, 30);

        nextPanel.setLayout(null);

        JButton battleButton = new JButton("Battle");
        JButton moveButton = new JButton("Teach Moves");
        JButton healButton = new JButton("Heal");

        battleButton.setBounds(0, 360, 500, 30);
        moveButton.setBounds(0, 390, 500, 30);
        healButton.setBounds(0, 420, 500, 30);

        moveButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                nextPanel.removeAll();
                nextPanel.updateUI();
                teachMove(c, nextPanel);

            }
        });

        nextPanel.add(battleButton);
        nextPanel.add(moveButton);
        nextPanel.add(healButton);
        nextPanel.add(title);

        for (int i = 0; i < newPlayer.moves.size(); i++) {
            moveLabelList.add(new JLabel(newPlayer.moves.get(i).toString()));
            moveLabelList.get(i).setBounds(185, yCoord, 100, 15);
            yCoord = yCoord + 25;
            nextPanel.add(moveLabelList.get(i));
        }

        yCoord = 100;

        for (int x = 0; x < newPlayer.damages.size(); x++) {
            damageLabelList.add(new JLabel(newPlayer.damages.get(x).toString() + " damage"));
            damageLabelList.get(x).setBounds(280, yCoord, 100, 15);
            yCoord = yCoord + 25;
            nextPanel.add(damageLabelList.get(x));
        }


        nextPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //nextPanel.setVisible(true);
        c.setVisible(true);
        c.add(nextPanel);
    }

    public static void teachMove(final Container x, final JPanel newPanel) {
        final int confirmYOrN = 0;

        final JTextField moveName = new JTextField();
        final JSlider moveDamage = new JSlider(0, 30);
        final JLabel confirm = new JLabel("Great! Your move has been added.");

        JLabel entryLabel = new JLabel("Enter the new move's name: ");
        JLabel damageEntryLabel = new JLabel("Enter the new move's damage: ");
        JButton enterButton = new JButton("OK");

        confirm.setBounds(160, 350, 200, 15);

        enterButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction("add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final String mName = moveName.getText();
                final int mDam = moveDamage.getValue();
                newPlayer.moves.add(mName);
                newPlayer.damages.add(mDam);

                newPanel.removeAll();
                newPanel.updateUI();

                battleGUISelection(x);

            }
        });

        moveDamage.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
        moveDamage.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
        moveDamage.setPaintTicks(true);
        moveDamage.setPaintLabels(true);

        entryLabel.setBounds(160, 125, 175, 25);
        damageEntryLabel.setBounds(160, 200, 200, 25);
        moveName.setBounds(160, 155, 175, 25);
        moveDamage.setBounds(160, 230, 175, 45);
        enterButton.setBounds(225, 290, 60, 50);

        newPanel.add(entryLabel);
        newPanel.add(moveName);
        newPanel.add(damageEntryLabel);
        newPanel.add(moveDamage);
        newPanel.add(enterButton);

        x.add(newPanel);
        x.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUICompoundLayout window = new GUICompoundLayout("BattleGUI");
        //Window properties
        window.setBounds(300, 300, 500, 500);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the UI I end up with...

[image]

Layout managers are your friend.  [Take the time to learn them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), they will save you many hours of frustration and annoyance.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try to help me out. i tried to just convert the panel for the GUISelection to flowlayout, just to see if it would make any difference, but it didn't. I've somewhat fixed my problem by cleaning up the code and rewriting most of it, but i think i will just find a different way to display the moves and damages. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see because it is a lot of code, but try calling repaint() instead of updateUI() on the panel.

Comment: sorry about the length..i tried to trim it as much as i could. Anyway, i tried the repaint() but it is still showing up blank. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set

```
nextPanel.setLayout(null);
```

which causes the panel to have a zero preferred size. Consider using a Layout Manager such as [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for this panel.